# Microservice and interface concept

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, microservices

I am planning to use a microservice architecture for my next development. At the moment I am learning about it. 
I was wondering if there is such thing as the interface concept for microservices. Something where each microservice can implement, like fulfilling a contract of endpoints it must contain. Then the other microservices can talk to it by knowing which end points may be available.

Comment: You have read about hypermedia? It addresses the need for "discovery" rather than hard-wiring stuff together. But it's aimed more towards resources explaining the "interface". So a mixture of hypermedia and a central Service Locator might be what you're looking for?

Comment: You may search for "_service registration and discovery_". Answers will tend to be language and framework specific.

Answer (score 0):

Designing/implementing some kind of contracts might be overkill for such a project, especially when you're at the learning phase. What works for us is a shared message bus that all the services talk to. You can read more about how we prototype those here: https://medium.com/@krawa76/bootstrap-node-js-microservice-stack-4a348db38e51